# Write to 2 datasources simultaneously when calling SaveAll in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, datasource, database-replication

I am trying to write values to 2 databases (need not be simultaneously) when the saveAll function is called. This does not apply to all tables but only 4 out of the 10 tables in the 2 databases.

My current logic, in Pseudocode:

```
    $updateOk = $model->saveAll(...);

    if (!$updateOk)
      return error;

    /* start second source synchronizing */
    $model->changeDataSource('second');
    $updateOk = $model->saveAll(...);

    $model->changeDataSource('default');
    if (!$updateOk)
        return error;

    return;
```

The issue with this is that sometimes it does not write to the second source, resulting in inconsistencies.

I need some advice on how to best solve this issue. I have 3 possible ideas:

1. Follow the code above and add checks to make sure things get saved and if it doest, rollback the default to maintain consistency
2. Write a server script that does a replication every time a saveAll() is called. (Resource intensive and not really scalable)
3. Use a combo of both. Do a check for consistency before saving and do a script replication once a day

Which is the best way or are there better ways of implementing this requirement? Any ways to ensure consistencies?

Comment: another idea might be to use `beforeSave` and/or `afterSave` to save the data to another Datasource. just an idea.

Comment: Yea I was planning to override the saveAll function instead. And add a check that its the table i want replicated do a switch and do a commit. This way the coder working in the controller doesnt have to know the complexity of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution possibly lies in database table replication (set up your second database as a slave, configured to replicate only specific tables).

Also, how will you ever scale this?

This way, you only need to worry about writing to the DB once (your models are going to get very bloated if you need all this extra code to write to two every time), plus you are allowing your app to scale horizontally in the future (think if your app was so big you required 20 x database servers?).

Another solution would be to create a shell task, scheduled on a cron job to move the data, but I would consider replication first.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly. I ended up setting up database replication for specific tables only (dint realize this was possible). Only issue is that apparently they tend to go out to sync apparently. So need to setup some sort of monitoring. For that I might end up using cron jobs to do a diff check or using tools like maatkit.